# How to use a regex to find a line without punctuation (ruby)

Tags: regex

What regex can I use to find lines in a block of text (i.e., paragraphs) that don't end in any punctuation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^.*[^\.!\?]$/
```

That regex will match any line that doesn't end in a period, a question mark, or an exclamation mark.  What other punctuation are you looking for?

Comment: That's totally perfect. Cheers!